# How to get main menu to highlight the link to the current page?

Tags: routes

My theme, [Riley](http://arrowtheme.com/riley), highlights menu item of the page that you're on. ([for example](http://arrowtheme.com/riley/projects-4columns)). I suspect this is a function of Drupal and not specific to the theme. First question: is this generally true?

If the answer to the first question is no and it is theme specific, then I can try to ask the theme makers the next question. Otherwise, my next question is, when I have multiple menu links that link to the current page, it will highlight the last link. How can I get it to highlight the first link instead? I am comfortable modifying PHP code.

For example, Menu Tab 1 contains link to current page P1 and deep within Menu Tab 2 also contains a link to P1, then it will only highlight the P1 link in Menu Tab 2.

Any thoughts / suggestions would be appreciated!

Setup: Apache 2.2, PHP 5.3, Drupal 7.34, PostgreSQL 9.2

Comment: This seems to be a Drupal internal thing. The theme is using the menu_tree_page_data function that Drupal construct including the active breadcrumb. Not sure if it's a feature or a bug that the active breadcrumb gives the last matching links precedence.

Answer (score 1):

normally this is accomplished via css in the theme, with the active attribute:

```
li a.ctive {
  ...
}
```

it is not core functionality. You could look at the different -child pseudo-elements to tweak it, or use some JS, but I think that portion of the question would be off-topic here - you are better off asking on stackoverflow